# Charts for Windows Phone Mango

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, charts, xna, windows-phone-7.1

I need to create charts for WP Mango. Therefore I have a couple of "what/how" questions which might be interesting:

What...

- ...frameworks or tools use for this purpose?
- ...better to use, Silverlight or XNA (or mix)?
- ...to read, download, avoid etc.?
- ...pitfalls in charts creation (even not for WP)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same Data Visualization project that supports charting on WPF and Silverlight supports Windows Phone 7.  Download the package and the data visualization demos from Delay's Blog:

- [Phone-y charts [Silverlight/WPF Data Visualization Development Release 4 and Windows Phone 7 Charting sample!]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/04/20/phone-y-charts-silverlight-wpf-data-visualization-development-release-4-and-windows-phone-7-charting-sample.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Telerik RadChart for WP7](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/chart.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for advice. But I prefer to use freeware/opensource stuff.

Comment: Well done. I appreciate that. Anyway i've heard only about this Chart controls.

Comment: Buy Telerik or build your own, there's not much of a choice really.

Answer (score 1):

I have found only 2 free Windows Phone chart libraries. Here are my posts with overview of these libraries:

1. [Silverlight Toolkit](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/silverlight-toolkit-charts-for-windows-phone-7/)
2. [AmCharts](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/windows-phone-7-chart-libraries-overview-amcharts/)

At the end of my posts I posted links to sample applications, so you can download and test them without writing your own samples.